How to assign a reader to TFDBatchMove::Reader in runtime?
Another question here lead me to a new problem. In C++ Builder I need to assign a reader to the TFDBatchMove::Reader property in runtime. The TFDBatchMove component is dropped on the form but then I need to assign the Reader property at runtime.
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TFDBatchMove *DBLoad;

Then in runtime I want to assign a reader:
DBLoad->Reader = new TFDBatchMoveTextReader(this);

This generates a compiler error :

[bcc32c Error] ResetForm.cpp(20): no viable conversion from
'Firedac::Comp::Batchmove::Text::TFDBatchMoveTextReader *' to
'Firedac::Comp::Batchmove::_di_IFDBatchMoveReader' (aka
'DelphiInterfaceFiredac::Comp::Batchmove::IFDBatchMoveReader')

It seems to be some DELPHI <> C++ conversion problem, but how do we solve it?

The error you quote suggests you should try = new TFDBatchMoveReader(this);

@RogerCigol I think it says it can't convert a pointer to an Interface.
